# TclError: couldn't load library "vtkRenderingTk-9.1.dll": this library or a dependent library could not be found in library path

Tags: python, tkinter, vtk

I tried to connect pyvista and tkinter and i am getting the above error. Here is the code for this. I have checked vtk is installed on my anaconda.

```
import tkinter
import pyvista

from vtk.tk.vtkTkRenderWindowInteractor import vtkTkRenderWindowInteractor


# Setup for root window
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("pyvista tk Demo")

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, side=tkinter.TOP)

# create an instance of a pyvista.Plotter to be used for tk
mesh = pyvista.Sphere()
pl = pyvista.Plotter()
pl.add_mesh(mesh)

# Setup for rendering window interactor
renwininteract = vtkTkRenderWindowInteractor(root, rw=pl.ren_win,width=400, height=400)
renwininteract.Initialize()
renwininteract.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
renwininteract.Start()

# Begin execution by updating the renderer and starting the tkinter
# loop
pl.render()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I assume the same thing happens if you replace all that code with just `import vtk.tk.vtkTkRenderWindowInteractor`, in which case this is a VTK issue rather than a PyVista issue. What is your VTK version and how did you install it?

Comment: This piece of code is working fine. Version of vtk is 9.1.0. I installed it using `pip install vtk` on anaconda powershell prompt.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce your issue. It's not a PyVista issue, because you only need `tkinter` to trigger it: `vtkTkRenderWindowInteractor(root)` will cause the same error. This should be raised with VTK, unless there's some kind of additional VTK package that needs to be installed to use Tk with it (I've never heard of any of this so I can't help you with that).